# Can I recover photos with photorec via bluetooth?

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, photorec

I've accidentally deleted photos that are on my phones internal memory. The only way to access my phone is via bluetooth, but photorec won't accept it as a valid target:

```
╰─$ photorec obex://[F4:9F:54:63:15:ED]/Images
PhotoRec 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Unable to open file or device obex://[F4:9F:54:63:15:ED]/Images

Usage: photorec [/log] [/debug] [/d recup_dir] [file.dd|file.e01|device]
       photorec /version

/log          : create a photorec.log file
/debug        : add debug information

PhotoRec searches various file formats (JPEG, Office...), it stores them
in recup_dir directory.

If you have problems with PhotoRec or bug reports, please contact me.
```

Is it possible to still recover my photos? Could I pipe it to photorec in some way, or image the phone via bluetooth and use photorec on that?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

If you made a raw image of the phone, you could run photorec on it.

Comment: And is there a way to make a raw image of the phone over bluetooth?

Comment: None that I'm aware of...

Comment: I wonder if the bluetooth protocol even allows that type of access, or if it just responds to file requests. My guess is the latter.. Which sucks, because that means my photos are lost..